# InterlockedBitTestAndReset64() is not defined

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I need to use InterlockedBitTestAndReset64() in my project but it seems not to be defined. I looked in the WinNT.h but the definition is greyed out due to the following preprocessor statements:

" #if defined(_M_AMD64) && !defined(RC_INVOKED) && !defined(MIDL_PASS) "

and

" #if defined(_M_IA64) && !defined(RC_INVOKED) && !defined(MIDL_PASS) "

I don't know what this mean.

**Is there any switches that I need to set in my project properties?**

I'm on Windows7 x64 and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
My CPU is an Intel Core2 Quad Q9450.

Edit: PS. I should mention that other 64bit functions like InterlockedAnd64 and InterlockedOr64
works fine. The InterlockedBitAndTestSet64, InterlockedBitTestAndReset64 seems to be the exception.

Thanks,
Karl

Comment: I think you should be able to construct an equivalent function using `InterlockedCompareExchange64()` and a loop.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I managed to us the InterlockedOr64 (Set) InterlockedAnd64 (Reset using ~ operator on the input value). And using a regular bitwise AND operator on the return value to check the previous bit values. This seems to work quite nicely.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you're doing, I mentioned `InterlockedCompareExchange64()` because things like it (AKA `CAS` = Compare And Swap) are used to construct atomic primitives, which are used in multi-threaded and multi-processor systems to avoid race conditions. If there's no chance of race conditions, you don't need things to be atomic. But if there is, this is a common solution.

Comment: What I need to do is to check if a bit is set in a specific 64bit number and if it's not it should be set it. And all of this needs to be done atomically. The InterlockedOr64() will set the desired bit and also will return a copy of the previous value. Since the return value is a local copy, it can be used in a regular non-atomic fashion (with a regular AND operator for example) to check whether it was already set or not. 

Also there is a similar version of the Reset function using InterlockedAnd64 and a regular AND. The InterlockedCompareExchange64() seems good alternative as well.

Comment: Ah, so it does all you need, great then.

Answer (score 4):

The _M_AMD64 macro is defined when you target the x64 platform.  The _M_IA64 macro is defined when you target an Itanium.  Both are 64-bit processors.  There's no support for this atomic operation on a 32-bit processor.  You can certainly target x64 with the processor and OS you have.

Comment: Thanks Hans. In the configuration manager I've set the Platform to x64 for my project. Is there anything else I need to set in order to target the x64 platform? Do I need to define _M_AMD64 myself (I don't think _M_IA64 is right for my processor)? The following definitions seems to be defined _M_X64, _M_IX86 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are **not** compiling for a x64 target, all the *64 functions are only available for x64 targets.

Comment: I've set the build configuration to x64 in the configuration manager, if this is what you mean? Other functions like InterlockedOr64 and InterlockedAnd64 works fine. InterlockedBitTest***64 functions seems to be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the problem by using an InterlockedOr64 and a regular AND operator and I think it turned out quite OK.

Example:
Instead of InterlockedBitTestAndSet64(...):

```
LONGLONG pattern = 0x0000000000001000;
bool result = InterlockedOr64(ptrToLonglong, pattern) & pattern;
```

Instead of InterlockedBitTestAndReset64(...):

```
LONGLONG pattern = 0x0000000000001000;
bool result = InterlockedAnd64(ptrToLonglong, ~pattern) & pattern;
```